# How to find single digits in a large string with regex php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have large strings that contain dates, single digit numbers and double digit numbers. I need to find and pad the single digit numbers (which could also be in the dates, as the months and days can possibly be single digits) with a preceding zero. The data is in this format:

m/d/yyyy 1,21,3,42,5,63,7,84,9

I need it in this format

mm/dd/yyyy 01,21,03,42,05,63,07,84,09

I've tried this:

```
$pattern = "#[9]{1}#m";
$str = preg_replace($pattern, "09, $str);
```

It kind of works, but for numbers like 29 that shouldn't be touched, it turns it into 209. Ideally I'd like to use a wildcard instead of a specific number so that it'll just pad all of the single digit numbers in the string but I haven't quite figured that part out. Any and all help would be appreciated , thanks.

Comment: What should happen for `0,0` or for example `#1#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match a digit 1-9 not surrounded by digits

```
(?<!\d)[1-9](?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O5tkvc/1)

Replace with a zero and the full match `0$0`

If you don't want to match the digits in the date, you can assert a comma or the end of the string to the right:

```
\b[1-9](?=,|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iTM2x4/1)

Comment: @Steve The first one or the second one? Did you see my question in the comments?

Comment: The first one worked for me. As for your questions above, I won't have single or double zeros to worry about in the strings, as for the #1#, I think this means if I need to pad with a 1 instead, that won't happen with my data, I only needed the zeros. Thanks again